# How to apply nth:child, when i have an element as a object in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem that how do i apply `nth:child` mechanism with an element which is as an object.

For Example:

`$('ul li:nth-child(4)').append('Anything');`

Now i have taken element into a `var`.

`var e = $('ul li');`

Now i want to apply the same `nth-child` functionality with element `e`. So my question is that how do i apply the same.

Comment: And where, does the php come in?

Comment: PHP people can also answer it. thats why i taged it.

Comment: That's not how it works, please only tag your questions with tags that involve your question, not with who you think can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to apply a conditional filter to a set of elements

```
var e = $('ul li');
e.filter(':nth-child(4)').append('Anything');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var e = $('ul li');
e.filter(':nth-child(4)').append('Anything');
```